# Jquery .each using array objects for arguments

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, arguments, each

I have an array...

```
var dataFilesArray =  [
   {data1: argumentA, file1: argumentB},
   {data2: argumentA, file2: argumentB}
   ]
```

For each data/file pair in the array, I would like to pass both values as arguments to function useData.

```
$.each(dataFilesArray {
   function useData (argumentA, argumentB)
});
```

Next loop would be for data2/file2, and so on until end of array.

```
function useData (argumentA, argumentB)
```

Can $.each be used this way?

Using

```
var dataFilesArray = [
    {data1: "someurl.com", file1: "somefileName.jpg"},
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing to do with `$.each`, it's just what you put in the callback you give it:

```
$.each(dataFilesArray, function(index, entry) {
    useData(entry.data, entry.file);
});
```

Note I used `data` and `file` above; you wouldn't want the property names in each object in your array to be different, so the array would be:

```
var dataFilesArray =  [
   {data: argumentA, file: argumentB},
   {data: argumentA, file: argumentB}
   ];
```

---

If they're **really** going to be `data1`/`file1` for the first entry, `data2/file2` for the next, etc., you *can* do that, but it's a very odd structure and it's delicate — if you change the contents of the array, you have to change all those names. But for completeness:

```
$.each(dataFilesArray, function(index, entry) {
    var num = index + 1;
    useData(entry["data" + num], entry["file" + num]);
});
```

Comment: **they're really** part is just awesome.

Comment: I am getting a RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND error.  The data is urls and filenames.  The urls are good.

Comment: @Jotter: The above works, there must be an issue applying it to your code.

Comment: You're right.  It works.  But I see your point, having the numbered names is not a good idea.   Since they are pairs and I want to iterate them as such.